# Are there some intrinsic invariants of surfaces other than Gaussian curvature?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, curvature, isometries

The principal  curvatures of a  surface is  denoted by $\kappa_{1}, \kappa_{2}$.

Let $P(x,y)$ be a polynomial with real  coefficients. Assume that $P(\kappa_{1}, \kappa_{2})$ is  an intrinsically invariant quantity of  all surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$(It is invariant under isometries of surfaces).

> Is it true to say that $P(x,y)$  is  in the form $P(x,y)=F(xy)$ for  some  one  variable  polynomial $F$?

In fact this  question, which is  motivated by ["Gauss  theorema  egregium"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium), asks:

> Are there  some  "Theorema Egregiums" other than "Gauss theorema  Egregium"?

Comment: a curve in a surface has the geodesic curvature as intrinsic invariant

Comment: This can be answered by considering different embeddings of a flat surface (flat plane vs cylinder).

Comment: @DeaneYang:  Actually, just using flat surfaces won't suffice:  The reason is that one of the principal curvatures will always be zero, so you won't be able to see, for example, that $P(\kappa_1,\kappa_2) = {\kappa_1}^2\kappa_2$ is not an intrinsic quantity by only considering flat surfaces.  Similarly, just using surfaces with some given fixed constant Gauss curvature $K_0$ won't provide you with enough examples to rule out all polynomials except those in the quantity $\kappa_1\kappa_2$.

Comment: First of  all,  if  $P(\kappa_1,\kappa_2)$  were a *universal* intrinsic invariant, i.e., one  that works for all surfaces, then  has to be symmetric in $\kappa_1,\kappa_2$. In particular, a *universal* intrinsic invariant will be a polynomial in $H=\kappa_1+\kappa_2$ and $K=\kappa_1\kappa_2$. Notice also that $H$ and $K$ rescale differently  when rescaling the surface.

Comment: Using the example of  @DeaneYang  we see that such a polynomial would need to satisfy $P(H,0)=P(0,0)$, for infinitely many $H$.

Comment: Let me see if I can get it right this time: As Liviu points out, an intrinsic polynomial $f$ has to be symmetric in the principal curvatures and therefore a polynomial in $H$ and $K$. It suffices to consider polynomials $f(H,K)$ such that $f(0,0) = 0$. Since $H$ can be any constant on circular cylinders, it follows that some power of $K$ divides $f$. Dividing by the highest power of $K$ that's a factor, we get either $1$ (so $f$ is a power of $K$) or a polynomial that does not vanish when $K = 0$ and therefore varies for different values of constant $H$.

Comment: @DeaneYang You do have to work harder than this. Suppose the only surfaces in the world were spheres ($H^2 = 4K$) and cylinders ($K=0$). Then $K(H^2-4K)$ would be an invariant. You need a family of surfaces that actually fills out a Zariski dense subset of the plane, like the pseudospheres.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As others have pointed out, it's not hard to show that any function $F(\kappa_1,\kappa_2)$ that is intrinsic to the surface metric must be a function of $K = \kappa_1\kappa_2$, so that settles what one might call the 'lowest-order' case.  However, there are certainly higher-order versions.  For example, the expression $|\nabla K|^2$ is an intrinsic invariant, and it can be expressed as a polynomial in the second fundamental form and its first covariant derivative (a good exercise in a curves and surfaces course).  One might want to think of this as a 'higher-order' version of Gauss' theorem, but it's not very exciting because, in some sense, it's a derivative of Gauss' theorem.

A natural question that arises (and the one that I thought the OP wanted to ask, based on the title of the question) is whether there is any higher-order theorem of this kind that is *not* just a derivative (of some order) of Gauss' theorem.  The answer to this question is 'no', in the following more precise sense:

Suppose given a surface described locally as a graph $z = f(x,y)$ where $f(0,0) = f_x(0,0) = f_y(0,0) = 0$, so that $f$ has a Taylor series expansion of the form
$$
f = \tfrac12 c_{20} x^2 + c_{11} xy + \tfrac12 c_{01} y^2 + \tfrac16 c_{30} x^3 + \cdots 
= \sum_{i+j\ge2} \tfrac1{i!j!} c_{ij}\, x^iy^j.
$$
Then Gauss' theorem says that $K(0,0) = c_{20}c_{02}-{c_{11}}^2$.
In fact, as is not difficult to show, if one takes the Taylor series of $K$ to be of the form
$$
K =  \sum_{i+j\ge0} \tfrac1{i!j!} b_{ij}\, x^iy^j,
$$
that there exist formulae of the form $b_{ij} = B_{ij}(c)$ where $B_{ij}$ is a universal polynomial in the $c_{kl}$ for which $k+l\le i+j+2$.  In fact, for each order $d$, one can collect these to define polynomial mappings
$$
B_d: \oplus_{k=2}^{d+2} S^k(\mathbb{R})\longrightarrow 
\oplus_{k=0}^{d}S^k(\mathbb{R})
$$
that represent the formula giving the Taylor series of $K$ to order $d$ in terms of the Taylor series of $f$ to order $d{+}2$.

The version of the question that I have in mind is whether every formula expressing an intrinsic invariant of the induced metric of finite order in terms of the second fundamental form and its covariant derivatives must factor through some $B_d$ at the series level. (Gauss' Theorem and the above arguments show that the answer is 'yes' for intrinsic invariants of order $0$.)  The answer is that, indeed, every finite order intrinsic invariant function on the domain of $B_d$ must factor through $B_d$.  This is a consequence of the usual proofs of the isometric embedding theorem for real-analytic surfaces.

Comment: Prof  Bryant,  thank  you very much for your very interesting answer and  consideration of extension of  my  question.

Answer (score 7):

A surfaces of constant curvature $K$ admit number of local embedding into $\mathbb{E}^3$ as the surfaces of revolution. Direct calculations show that any pair $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that $K=k_1\cdot k_2$ appear this way.

So, "yes", any $P(x,y)=F(x\cdot y)$ for some $F$.

Comment: Thank you so much  for  your very interesting complete answer.